# Exponential re-rendering with eventListener on state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to use an `eventListener` on "keydown" that'll update my state (a boolean named `showMenu`).
I've placed it on the `useEffect`, but it does not work properly and I can't figure out why...
It re-renders the component exponentially if I put `showMenu` on the array at the end of my useEffect.
If I don't put `showMenu` at the end of my `useEffect`, the `showMenu` will only be updated once (from false to true)

Here is the code that re-renders exponentially

```
const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => handleMenu(e));
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", (e) => handleMenu(e));
    };
}, [showMenu]);

const handleMenu = (e) => {
    if (e.key == "m") {
        setShowMenu(!showMenu);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeEventListener` takes a function *reference* but you are creating an anonymous function each time:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleMenu);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleMenu);
    };
}, [showMenu]);
```

By removing the anonymous function wrapper (aka eta reduction) addEventListener and removeEventListener get the same function reference.

Alternatively if you only support modern browsers and want to ignore the concept of function references addEventListener supports `AbortSignal`s:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const ac = new AbortController();
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => handleMenu(e), { signal: ac.signal });
    return () => ac.abort();
}, [showMenu]);
```

---

As a side note there is really no reason to pass `showMenu` into the dependency list of the function and I'd not pass it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do I need to put the `handleMenu` at the end of the `useEffect` ? If this is what you mean, I still have an exponential rendering... Maybe I need to use another hook?

Comment: @feyndev after second thought (added a comment) I would not pass anything to `useEffect` as a dependency list - the list is "run this effect whenever that dependency changed" - since your effect isn't stateful (it just attaches a listener and the state is in the app) there is no real point in setting the listener when stuff changes only when the component unmounts.

Comment: But the function is not called when the keydown on "m" is made.. The state changes only once. How can I update my state every time I type on the key without using useEffect ?

Comment: When performing a side effect like manually editing the DOM you _need_ to use useEffect. I think you have to pass `showMenu` to the dependency list since the function reference changes and the value of it. Kind of unfortunate I'll update the answer.

Comment: I understand your answer, I posted the working code below. Thank you for taking the time ! I appreciate it mate :)

Comment: 1 hour spent on this, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

OK just figured it out.
The useEffect method was not the problem. The logic is good.
The issue was with the `(e) => handleMenu(e)` that I need to change to `handleMenu` directly.
See below:

```
const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

const handleMenu = (e) => {
    if (e.key == "m") {
        setShowMenu(!showMenu);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleMenu);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleMenu);
    };
}, [showMenu]);
```

Kudos to Benjamin for giving me the answer : I needed to pass my handleMenu function reference instead of using `(e) =>` syntax which creates a new function each time based on my handleMenu function, it explains the exponential rendering :)